# Xcode6 creating an empty xib file for iPhone? Size is too big

Tags: ios, iphone, interface, xcode6, xib

I am working my way through an IOS programming book. I need to create an empty xib file in an objective C project, I add a view to this file and the view is large/square shaped. I'm not sure how to make this canvas the right size for the iPhone. Can someone please help me? Thanks!

Comment: You get this sorted out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have size classes enabled, which is a new feature in iOS 8. To make your nib match your book disable size classes then resize the nib to iPhone size.

Select the nib and show the "File Inspector" then deselect "Use Size Classes":

[image]

Then resize the nib to be iPhone sized by selecting the `View` in the nib (.xib) file and then click the "Size Inspector" and update the size of the view.

[image]

[image]

Comment: sorry just saw this late! thank you so much for taking the time to answer! got it sorted

Answer (score 0):

if this is xcode 6 and you want to disable size classes, you need to select your view, go to property inspector,select first tab and uncheck "use size classes"